# Match value in multiple sheets array

Tags: arrays, excel-2010, matching

I have a workbook with 8 sheets that contain a score in the same cell (I28). The sheets are named after the participants and contain spaces. I want to know which is the highest score of the 8 and, more difficult, who has that score.

The highest score is easy to retrieve with MAX or LARGE function (=MAX('Sheet1:Sheet8'$I$28), but I'm having difficulty matching this high score to the participant getting that score. The participant's name is nowhere on the sheet, it's only the sheet name that has the reference.

How can I have Excel match the highest score to the right participant without listing the scores first? And would it be possible to list more names in case of equal scores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this small User Defined Function:

```
Public Function PersonOfInterest()
    Dim v As Variant, nam As String
    Application.Volatile
    nam = Sheet1.Name
    v = Sheet1.Range("J28").Value
    For i = 2 To 8
        v2 = Sheets(i).Range("J28").Value
        If v2 > v Then
            v = v2
            nam = Sheets(i).Name
        End If
    Next i

    PersonOfInterest = nam
End Function
```

**EDIT#1:**

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=myfunction(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

**EDIT#2:**

This version will return more than one name:

```
Public Function PersonsOfInterest()
    Dim v As Variant, nam As String
    Dim i As Long, v2 As Variant
    Application.Volatile
    nam = Sheet1.Name
    v = Sheet1.Range("J28").Value
    For i = 2 To 8
        v2 = Sheets(i).Range("J28").Value
        If v2 > v Then
            v = v2
        End If
    Next i

    PersonsOfInterest = ""
    For i = 1 To 8
        If Sheets(i).Range("J28").Value = v Then
            If PersonsOfInterest = "" Then
                PersonsOfInterest = Sheets(i).Name
            Else
                PersonsOfInterest = PersonsOfInterest & ", " & Sheets(i).Name
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Though I'm not completely green wrt VBA, could you enlighten me where and how to implement this code?  I want the name returned in a cell, by the way.

Comment: @H.Vink  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Thanks, that works like a charm when I leave the brackets empty. It however does not show multiple names when participant have the same highest score, which is actually the case. Could you help out with that as well please?

Comment: @H.Vink  See my **EDIT#2**